# C Language: Implement an array containing BST's of strings ( words ) from a text file

Tags: c, arrays, string, tree, crash

I am trying to create a small program that reads words from a text file of an unknown size and stores those words into an array of Binary Search Trees ( BST ) .  Each index within the array represents the length of the words within that BST tree.

For example, index 0 contains no words but index 1 contains a BST tree with words that are one letter long and index 5 contains a BST tree with words that are 5 letters long etc.  All BST trees are balanced by comparing two strings to determine if the new string is greater or smaller than the root string and then assigned accordingly.

My original code contains opaque objects ( void pointers ). But, I have included a smaller version of the program that I am trying to understand.  I included `printf` statements to show my debugging approach because the program keeps crashing.  I have been working on this for hours on end daily and can't get it to run for the life of me.  For some reason I couldn't determine if I was using the pointers properly so after about 5 different rewrites of this code, I decided to go with just the basics, but I can't seem to get this to work either.

Please help, this is draining me. Thank you for your generosity and consideration in helping me with this in advance.

My output is as follows:

```
A CHECKPOINT
B CHECKPOINT
C CHECKPOINT
1 CHECKPOINT
2 CHECKPOINT
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct my_string{
char* data;
struct my_string *left, *right;
} My_string;

void init( My_string* Root, char* data );

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    My_string* myStringArray[ 30 ] = {NULL};
    /*My_string* Root = NULL;*/
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char new_string[ 30 ];
    fp = fopen( "dictionary.txt", "r");
    int string_length = 0;
    printf( "A CHECKPOINT\n");
    while( fscanf( fp, "%1024s" , new_string ) == 1 ){
        printf( "B CHECKPOINT\n");
        string_length = strlen( new_string );
        printf( "C CHECKPOINT\n");
        init( myStringArray[ string_length ], new_string );
        printf( "D CHECKPOINT\n");
    }
    printf( "" );
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void init( My_string* Root, char* data ){
    printf( "1 CHECKPOINT\n");
    int compare = 0;
    if( Root == NULL ){
        printf( "2 CHECKPOINT\n");
        (*Root).data = ( My_string* )malloc( sizeof( My_string ));
         printf( "3 CHECKPOINT\n");
        if( !Root ) exit(1);
        Root->data = data;
        Root->left = Root->right = NULL;
    }
    else{
        if( compare = strncmp( data, Root->data, 36 ) == 0 )return;
        else if( compare == -1 ) init( Root->left, data );
        else init( Root->right, data );
    }
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: The simplified code that I provided is indeed a BST.  I left the balancing out for the AVL because it is not where the problem lies with this code.  I tried to simplify the code as much as possible to get to the issue.  I am fairly new to StackOverflow, if I can I will change the header to read BST. Thank you.

Comment: You pass a null pointer as `Root` to your `init` function; your code crashes when you dereference it.  This is not very surprising.  You need to pass `&myStringArray[string_length]` to the function, and the function needs to take `My_string **Root`.  There are then corresponding changes to make — but the `malloc()` line would probably need an arrow `->` instead of a dot `.`, I think (or maybe you need just `*Root = malloc(…);`.  The `Root->data` line would become `(*Root)->data` and `(*Root)->left`, etc.  I've only compiled it mentally.  Don't forget to error check memory allocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two general advices:

1. Instead of debug-output you can use debugger to find the exact location of the error (learn how to use `gdb`, for example). You can use debug-output, of course, but it can take more time and you have to clean up after this.
2. Don't ignore compiler warnings.

My compiler says:

```
a.c:37:22: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
(*Root).data = ( My_string* )malloc( sizeof( My_string ));
```

Here you try to dereference `Root` and assign a value to `data` field. Since `Root` is `NULL`, the program crashes here. It looks like you intended to assign value to `Root` here, but made a type of kind.
So it should be something like this:

```
Root = ( My_string* )malloc( sizeof( My_string ));
```

BTW, you have another problem in the code: when you pass `Root` as function parameter, it won't be changed after you exit the function:

```
My_string* Root = NULL;
init(Root, data);
// Root is NULL here
```

One way to fix this is to pass pointer to `Root`:

```
init(&Root, data);
void init( My_string** Root_ptr, char* data ){
    ...
}
```

and modify the code accordingly.

Another way is to change `init` signature and make it return a newly-created `Root`. I don't understand the scenario where you need to init an existing tree, so it seems a natural thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The suggestions that you provided worked like a charm. Also, I will be sure to look into gdb.